# Dual monitor on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

This is my first time dealing with the problem of dual display.

Here's the detail of my laptop:

TF-T5-SKELAKE:

- CPU: i7-6700HQ
- Graphics:

  - Intel HD 530
  - NVIDIA GTX 970M
- Thunderbold ports

After the installation of Ubuntu 16.04, I did three things first:

1. Disabled nouveau driver in kernel module (this driver caused my laptop crashed badly)
2. Installed the latest driver of Intel HD 530 from proprietary.
3. Installed the latest driver of NVIDIA GTX 970M from proprietary.

> Notice that the latest NVIDIA's driver contains a component called PRIME, which is made for switching graphic cards on Linux.

Under this condition, I found that:

- When I set to use Intel driver in PRIME, new individual monitor cannot be recognized.
- When I set to user NVIDIA driver in PRIME, new individual monitor can be recognized, BUT I cannot set to expand display on new monitor(like Windows does), and my whole desktop became a huge one with the resolution of (1920*2) x 1080.

So, is there any way I can set the two monitor(the original one on laptop, and the new individual one) working as expanded display?

Comment: I think, in hybrid laptops, there is one output port for each of the graphics cards to function properly. So if you switch the Prime profile , you would need to switch the output port connection. If you don't then the proprietary drivers drive your laptop display but the secondary display is driven by xorg drivers and its not clean..

Comment: see if [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) helps.

Comment: @astrob0t Thanks for your comment. I think this should work.